# Why is Xcode 5 telling me I have duplicate symbols for C library functions when building for the simulator (i386)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, ld

I have an existing iOS app project that builds fine for device and and simulator on Xcode 4. When I try to build the same project on Xcode 5 for the simulator, I get "duplicate symbols" for numerous (>800) C standard library functions for many (all?) of the object files, like this:

```
Ld Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Uploader.app/Uploader normal i386
cd /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
setenv PATH     "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/cmarkle/gcutil-1.2.0:/aspera/bin:/Users/cmarkle/bin:/Users/cmarkle/devel/android-sdk/platform-tools:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/usr/lib/system -L/Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/imports/objc-utils/build/Release-iphoneuniversal -F/Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2 -F/Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/imports/session_manager/release/framework -filelist /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iphone_upload_app.build/Objects-normal/i386/Uploader.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lobjc-utils -all_load -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -liconv -lz -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework MediaPlayer -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AudioToolbox -framework MessageUI -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AssetsLibrary -framework QuartzCore -framework AsperaMobile -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iphone_upload_app.build/Objects-normal/i386/Uploader_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Uploader.app/Uploader

duplicate symbol _isascii in:
    /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/ \    
        Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ \
        iphone_upload_app.build/Objects-normal/i386/AsTransferViewController.o
    /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/ \ 
        Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ \ 
        iphone_upload_app.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o

duplicate symbol ___istype in:
    /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/ \
        Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ \ 
        iphone_upload_app.build/Objects-normal/i386/AsTransferViewController.o
    /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/ \
        Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ \
        iphone_upload_app.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o

[... 842 more examples deleted ...]

duplicate symbol ___sigbits in:
    /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/ \
        Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ \
        iphone_upload_app.build/Objects-normal/i386/AsTransferViewController.o
    /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/ \
        Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ \
        iphone_upload_app.build/Objects-normal/i386/PresetsViewController.o

duplicate symbol ___sputc in:
    /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/ \
        Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ \
        iphone_upload_app.build/Objects-normal/i386/AsTransferViewController.o
    /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/ \
        Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ \
        iphone_upload_app.build/Objects-normal/i386/PresetsViewController.o

ld: 846 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I look in the created object files I do see the C standard library functions included in the object (showing as type T in nm output):

```
$ nm -n /Users/cmarkle/devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/ \ 
            Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/i \ 
            iphone_upload_app.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o
         U _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoreleasePool
         U _UIApplicationMain
         U __DefaultRuneLocale
         U ___maskrune
         U ___sincos_stret
         U ___sincosf_stret
         U ___sincospi_stret
         U ___sincospif_stret
         U ___swbuf
         U ___tolower
         U ___toupper
00000000 T _isascii
         U _objc_msgSend
00000030 T ___istype
000000d0 T ___isctype
00000150 T ___wcwidth
000001f0 T _isalnum
00000220 T _isalpha
[... more follow ...]
00000ba0 T ___sincospif
00000bf0 T ___sincospi
00000c50 T ___sigbits
00000ca0 T ___sputc
00000d40 T _main    
00002fc0 s EH_frame0
00002fd8 S _isascii.eh
00002ff4 S ___istype.eh
[... eh (debugging?) stuff
000034c4 S ___sigbits.eh
000034e0 S ___sputc.eh
000034fc S _main.eh
```

I have the "Link with Standard Libraries" set to YES as is normally done for apps. If I set it to NO (which doesn't make any sense but I'm just sayin') I get hundreds of `Undefined symbols for architecture i386: xxx` messages for all kinds of C standard library functions.

I've done all the lame things like cleaned my project, deleted the Derived Data, etc.

As a test I made a new dummy Xcode 5 single-view iOS project, made sure I used a C standard library function in it (`memset`) and looked at the main.o created when I compiled that project for the simulator. Here's how it looked (note that memset is U which means its not included in the object).

```
$ nm main.o
000004ac s EH_frame0
         U _NSStringFromClass
         U _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate
         U _UIApplicationMain
         U ___stack_chk_fail
         U ___stack_chk_guard
00000000 T _main
000004c4 S _main.eh
         U _memcpy
0000049b s _memcpy$stub
         U _memset
000004a0 s _memset$stub
         U _objc_autoreleasePoolPop
         [... more U _objc_xxx ...]
         U _objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
```

For reference, here's an example of the compile step for one of the offending object files:

```
CompileC Build/Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iphone_upload_app.build/Objects-normal/i386/AsTransferViewController.o Classes/AsTransferViewController.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/cmarkle/gcutil-1.2.0:/aspera/bin:/Users/cmarkle/bin:/Users/cmarkle/devel/android-sdk/platform-tools:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/  \
    usr/bin/clang 
    -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack 
    -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 
    -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes 
    -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak 
    -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label 
    -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body 
    -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants 
    -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion 
    -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof 
    -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector 
    -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DAPPLE -DDEBUG 
    -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk 
    -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations 
    -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 
    -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 
    -iquote /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iphone_upload_app.build/Uploader-generated-files.hmap 
    -I/Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iphone_upload_app.build/Uploader-own-target-headers.hmap 
    -I/Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iphone_upload_app.build/Uploader-all-target-headers.hmap 
    -iquote /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iphone_upload_app.build/Uploader-project-headers.hmap 
    -I/Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/imports/objc-utils/build/Debug-iphoneos/include/ASOCUtils 
    -I/Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/imports/objc-utils/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/ASOCUtils -I/Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/imports/objc-utils/build/Release-iphoneos/include/ASOCUtils 
    -I/Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/imports/objc-utils/build/Release-iphonesimulator/include/ASOCUtils 
    -I/Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iphone_upload_app.build/DerivedSources/i386 
    -I/Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iphone_upload_app.build/DerivedSources 
    -F/Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator 
    -F/Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2 
    -F/Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/imports/session_manager/release/framework 
    -fgnu89-inline 
    -include /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/iphone_upload_app_Prefix-gyxexsjpqpprnwefzartfgpgjyug/iphone_upload_app_Prefix.pch 
    -MMD -MT dependencies 
    -MF /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iphone_upload_app.build/Objects-normal/i386/AsTransferViewController.d 
    --serialize-diagnostics /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iphone_upload_app.build/Objects-normal/i386/AsTransferViewController.dia 
    -c /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Classes/AsTransferViewController.m 
    -o /Users/cmarkle/Devel/uploader/uploader-rel-2.0.0-copied-imports-2/Build/Intermediates/iphone_upload_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iphone_upload_app.build/Objects-normal/i386/AsTransferViewController.o
```

So... can anyone help me figure out why I am getting duplicate symbols for C standard library functions in my objects when I build for simulator? Thanks in advance. Happy to provide more information if requested...

EDIT 1: Per Rob's and Petesh's comments below I took out the `-fgnu89-inline` option from Build Settings > Apple LLVM 5.0 - Custom Compiler Flags > Other C Flags, at which point my project compiled fine for i386 / simulator.

I also made a new single view app using the Xcode wizard and compiled it as-is for the simulator, which worked as expected. I then added the `-fgnu89-inline` option to the Build Settings, at which point the build failed with ~180 duplicate symbols.

Definitely related to the `-fgnu89-inline` option when using clang...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE

You're using the `-fgnu89-inline` compiler flag for some reason.  That flag tells the compiler that functions tagged `inline` should still be emitted in the object file as exported symbols.  That's why the compiler complains that `main.o` and `AsTransferViewController.o` contain duplicate symbols.  None of those duplicate symbols should be exported from any of your `.o` files.  Get rid of that compiler flag.

### ORIGINAL

If you look at the definition of `isascii` (in `/usr/include/ctype.h`), you'll find this:

```
__DARWIN_CTYPE_TOP_inline int
isascii(int _c)
{
        return ((_c & ~0x7F) == 0);
}
```

You will find that `__DARWIN_CTYPE_TOP_inline` is defined in the same file like this:

```
#define __DARWIN_CTYPE_TOP_inline       __header_inline
```

And you will find `__header_inline` defined in `/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h` like this:

```
/* Declaring inline functions within headers is error-prone due to differences
 * across various versions of the C language and extensions.  __header_inline
 * can be used to declare inline functions within system headers.  In cases
 * where you want to force inlining instead of letting the compiler make
 * the decision, you can use __header_always_inline.
 *
 * Be aware that using inline for functions which compilers may also provide
 * builtins can behave differently under various compilers.  If you intend to
 * provide an inline version of such a function, you may want to use a macro
 * instead.
 *
 * The check for !__GNUC__ || __clang__ is because gcc doesn't correctly
 * support c99 inline in some cases:
 * http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55965
 */

#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L && (!defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__))
# define __header_inline           inline
#elif defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__GNUC_STDC_INLINE__)
# define __header_inline           extern __inline __attribute__((__gnu_inline__))
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
# define __header_inline           extern __inline
#else
  /* If we land here, we've encountered an unsupported compiler,
   * so hopefully it understands static __inline as a fallback.
   */
# define __header_inline           static __inline
#endif
```

Normally, `__header_inline` is defined in a way that prevents the symbol (e.g. `isascii`) from being exported in the `.o` file.  I suspect you are doing something that is causing `__header_inline` to be defined improperly, so the symbol is being exported.  Since the symbol is being exported in two `.o` files that you're linking together, you get a linker error.

You can ask Xcode to show you the preprocessor output by choosing Product > Perform Action > Preprocess “*filename*” from the menu bar.  Look through the preprocessor output for `main.m` and see how `isascii` is being declared.  This is what I get:

```
inline int
isascii(int _c)
{
 return ((_c & ~0x7F) == 0);
}
```

If you get something different (in particular, something not declared `inline`), you need to figure out why.

Comment: I think the problem is with the `-fgnu89-inline` flag

Comment: Rob - Preprocessor shows:
`inline int
isascii(int _c)
{
 return ((_c & ~0x7F) == 0);
}`
same as you got. But per Petesh's comment, I removed the -fgnu89-line option from Build Settings > Apple LLVM 5.0 > Custom Compile Flags > Other C Flags, and the project built for i386 / simulator without incident. I'd still like to use this as a learning experience... Is there more that comes to mind that we can look at to see what really happened here?

Comment: All I have to do is add this `-fgnu89-inline` to a Xcode-generated single view app project and it will fail to build for the simulator...

Comment: I think when you specify `-fgnu89-inline`, it tells the compiler that a function tagged `inline` (like `isascii`) should be inlined where possible in the current compilation unit, and also emitted as a regular function in the object file.  See the paragraph starting with “When an inline function is not `static`” in [§6.39 of the gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html).

Comment: Rob - How about updating your answer just a bit to get Petesh's and your comments about -fgnu89-inline into the answer, then I'll accept it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

if you used the same instance variable name in two different files and if both of them are outside of methods, then once you import the first file in to the second one, you get this duplicate symbols error. Check if it is the issue.